# Firefox not storing cookies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, firefox, cookies

Mozilla firefox not storing auth cookies set by my express js server.
[image: Although firefox is receiving the cookies on request completion]

As per the image, firefox is receiving the cookies from the server but doesn't seem to be storing them.

[image: Cookie not stored by the browser]

I am using this particular cookie for authentication, which is breaking the website's whole functionality.

Here's a screenshot of the console
[image: Screenshot of Console]

How can I fix this thing?

Website URL: https://cinehubb.vercel.app/home

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your server and you client are on the same domain, because in other case you can not access cookies from your code.
2. About SameSite. Set sameSite to 'none' 
   There is a cookie option there: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html

Comment: I have hosted my backend on Heroku, and the frontend is on Vercel, they are not on the same domain;
API link: http://cinehub-wiki.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You need them to be on one domain. And set SameSite to none.

Comment: nvm, fixed it, just had to change the domain to that of where the backend is hosted.